# Equations of the form $((\Delta)^{2}+\lambda\Delta+\gamma)(f)=0$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations, elliptic-pde

Here is the problem: I am trying to figure out if there is a non-zero solution for the system of equations:

$(\Delta^{k-1}+a)(d^{\ast}\eta)=2d^{\ast}d\xi$

$(\Delta^{k}+b)(d\xi)=2dd^{\ast}\eta$

for $a,b$ constants both different to zero, $\Delta^{k-1}$ is the Hodge Laplacian on $k-1$ forms on a compact manifold $\Sigma$, analogous for $\Delta^{k}$. We need to solve for  $d^{\ast}\eta$ a co-exact $k-1$ form and $d\xi$ a exact $k$-form.

Using standard Hodge decomposition we easily obtain necessary conditions:

$d^{\ast}\eta=(-1/2a)(\Delta^{k-1}+b-4)(d^{\ast}d\xi)$

and

$((\Delta^{k-1})^{2}+(b+a-4)\Delta^{k-1}+ab)d^{\ast}d\xi=0$

Therefore a necessary condition on the constants $a,b$ is that

$Ker((\Delta^{k-1})^{2}+(b+a-4)\Delta^{k-1}+ab)\cap d^{\ast}(\wedge^{k}T^{\star}\Sigma)\neq0$

**My question is the following:**

Given a compact Riemannian manifold $\Sigma$, ***what do we know about the equation***

$((\Delta)^{2}+\lambda\Delta+\gamma)(f)=0$

Where $\Delta$ is the Hodge-Laplacian acting on forms (or functions) and $\lambda, \gamma$ are cosntants.

***Do we have conditions on $\lambda, \gamma$ that imply a non-trivial kernel?***

Thanks

EDIT:

Observe that if $\theta$ is an eigenvector of $\Delta$ i.e. $\Delta(\theta)=\alpha \theta$ with $\alpha\neq 0$ then

$((\Delta)^{2}+\lambda\Delta+\gamma)(\theta)=\alpha^{2}\theta+\lambda\alpha\theta+\gamma\theta=(\alpha^{2}+\lambda\alpha+\gamma)\theta$

Therefore $((\Delta)^{2}+\lambda\Delta+\gamma)(\theta)=0$ with $\theta\neq 0$ if the eigenvalue $\alpha$ satisfies $\alpha^{2}+\lambda\alpha+\gamma=0$

**Question: do the eigenvectors $\theta$ with eigenvalues $\alpha$ satisfying $\alpha^{2}+\lambda\alpha+\gamma=0$ exhaust all the elements in the kernel of  $(\Delta)^{2}+\lambda\Delta+\gamma$** ?

thanks

Comment: Doesn't this follow from the spectral theorem for $\Delta$?  Write $f = \sum_{i=1}^\infty f_i$ where each $f_i$ is an eigenfunction of $\Delta$ with a different eigenvalue (and the $f_i$ are thus pairwise orthogonal), and apply $\Delta^2 + \lambda \Delta + \gamma$ termwise.

Comment: Actually your comment is quite true: by writing $f=\Sigma f_{i}$ we obtained that $(\Delta^{2}+\lambda\Delta+\gamma)(f)=0$ if and only if $\alpha^{2}_{i}+\lambda\alpha_{i}+\gamma=0$ for all $i$. Hence the kernel of  $\Delta^{2}+\lambda\Delta+\gamma$ is not trivial if and only if $\frac{-\lambda\pm\sqrt{\lambda^{2}-4\gamma}}{2}$ are eigenvalues of $\Delta$. Thanks for your suggestion.